# Multiple values on same index

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I am doing a small code test at a place called Experis. And while the assigment itself was fine, the problem lies when I try to fetch the input from their servers.
There are multiple inputs that needs to be tested, however instead of being sent in an array, they are all sent at once.
Which itself is fine, I just use "`line.split(' ')`" to split every sentence into its own word.
However after I try to call the first part with `"line[0]`" I get a very weird result, instead of just sending the first word, it sends the first letter of every word.
The inputs are:

at
ordeals
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmabcdefghijklm
abcdABCDabcd

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    var nums = line.split(' ');
    
    console.log(nums);
});
```

Expected result:
at

Actual result:
a
o
a
a
a

I have tried to parse the data, turn it into an array, using different kinds of spliting, but nothing I try seem to work properly.
I have contacted their support team, but since it is weekend they don't seem to answer.
And at this point I am desperate for help.

Edit:

logging line gave me at `ordeals abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmabcdefghijklm abcdABCDabcd` in type string,string,string,string,string.

While logging nums gives me: [ 'at' ] [ 'ordeals' ] [ 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' ] [ 'abcdefghijklmabcdefghijklm' ] [ 'abcdABCDabcd' ] in type object,object,object,object,object.
Which makes it so that if I log nums[0] then I get the entirety of input again in string,string,string,string,string.

Comment: Try logging `line`

Comment: @Spectric 

Logging line gave me 

`at
ordeals
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmabcdefghijklm
abcdABCDabcd`

in type string,string,string,string,string

Comment: What does logging `nums` gives you?

Comment: @Spectric

Logging nums gives me:

`[ 'at' ]
[ 'ordeals' ]
[ 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' ]
[ 'abcdefghijklmabcdefghijklm' ]
[ 'abcdABCDabcd' ]` as object object object object object

Comment: Oh wait - you should be logging `nums[0]`, not `lines[0]`

Comment: @Spectric

I forgot to mention that when I log nums[0] I get the entirety of the input again.
`at
ordeals
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmabcdefghijklm
abcdABCDabcd`

as string,string,string,string,string

Comment: Something very strange is going on with your computer.

Comment: @Spectric

I write the code on their website, and then they compile it for me, so there is something wrong on their end xD 
I have contacted customer support, but they haven't answered xD

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var nums = line.split(/\s/);
```

Comment: Sadly it gives the same result :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Try logging what is `JSON.stringify({line})` and `JSON.stringify({nums})`

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    var nums = line.split(' ');
    
    // expected: '{line: "at ordeals ... " }'
    console.log(JSON.stringify({line}));
    // expected: '{nums: ["at", "ordeals", ...] }'
    console.log(JSON.stringify({nums}));
});
```

JSON and object is to check if you understand its correctly and escape \n, \t, etc